# pull all info inside li by searching for a specific value inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, html-lists

hello I am working a chrome extension that controls a website and there are these lists:

It looks like this:

```
<ul class="styles">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
etc..
```

each li contains custom data

I want to be able to pull all the data inside the one I want by seaching for its

```
data-style-name= "Orange"
href="/example"
```

I want to be able to search for which li's data--style-name= "Orange"

then pull a specific result from it like the href=

so something like this:

```
const searchStr = "orange";
const lowerSearchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase(); 
const foundItem = (ul .styles all the lis??).find(
    ({ data-name }) => data-name.toLowerCase().includes(lowerSearchStr)
);
```

something like that would work I think.

I want to find the data-name maybe with a keyword as well as the full name

but then pull the specific href thats inside the found li.

Thank You for taking the time to read this and I would really appreciate it if you could help me out ;) <3

Comment: Can you post the *actual* HTML (or mocked-up HTML) rather than an empty list? Also, if you're searching `li`s, why would an `li` have an `href` attribute? Sounds like you're just looking for `querySelector`

Comment: The code on screenshot simply stores the attribute values in a deduplicated array. As for the problem, it's likely the site constructs the page slightly after the extension's content script runs. To fight this an extension must poll the page periodically using setTimeout/setInterval or use MutationObserver or other events, see [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: the lis in the url you given doesnt have any data attribute, they have a class and style

Comment: wdym by poll the page periodically? @wOxxOm

Comment: [Make function wait until element exists](//stackoverflow.com/q/16149431)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be purely in javascript and below code is same as you have in your screenshot,

```
search_str       = "orange"; 
search_attr_name = "data-style-name"; 
var all_styles   = my_document.querySelectorAll("[data-style-name]");
matching_url     = "";

if(all_styles.length){
    all_styles.forEach(function(e){ 
        var data_style_name = e.attributes[search_attr_name].value; 
        console.log("TEST data_style_name: ", data_style_name);

        if(data_style_name.length && data_style_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_str) > -1) { 

            if(typeof e.attributes["href"].value !== "undefined"){ 
                matching_url = e.attributes["href"].value 
            } 
        }                           
    }); 

    console.log("matching_url: " + matching_url); 
}
```

Comment: Its not working for some reason can I maybe email you my entire js file so you can see why its not working? my email is wojprod@gmail.com

Comment: can you share teamviewer id & pass using other means like whatsapp, gmail etc. I know this is the solution & I wants to show it on your computer.

Comment: I don't know what teamviewer is?  could I just email you my code?

Comment: when I run that entire code in the console I just get undefined as a response

Comment: you can download it from https://www.teamviewer.com download the appropriate version you require & I will let you connect to my laptop for demo.

Comment: Ok I have teamview whats your email so I can email you my password

Comment: i sent it bhagwanparge

Comment: I tried to connect but "reason unknown" msg is getting displayed & also you have not mailed your password. I have modified the answer as per your requirement, try it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179697/discussion-between-developer12-and-bhagwanparge).

Comment: Instead of map() function you can use forEach() & your main problem was you were trying to process the html before it is received.

Comment: check the chat @bhagwanparge

Answer (score 0):

You will need to process each li, as like this,

```
$("li").each(function() {
allDatas = $(this).data();
search_str = "left";

$.each(allDatas, function(key, val) {
    if(val.length && val.indexOf(search_str) > -1) {
        console.log(val);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: are you searching in the style attribute of the li tag?

Comment: i dont think I can use jquery in my background.js script for some reason

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange

Comment: if you can't use jquery then it is not an issue we can convert it into javascript but what is your aim on the given webpage?

Comment: I want to find the li that matches the data-style-name ,, so then It searched for which one matches Orange, then gets the href inside that specific li ,, so I want to console.log the href

Comment: I am unable to find data-style-name or style-name or styleName or Orange can you point me after which text or html i can find this.

Comment: when you click on the url I have above, right click on the orange hat icon you see in the page and click inspect element, you should see it then

Comment: were you able to find it??

Comment: I am able to find the mentioned attribute at a different url https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/hats/jkvzxqiy8/x5c7nlja8 & it is not associated with li but with a tag ... check once & confirm?

Comment: the url you seem to be giving me doesnt exist, are you in europe by chance?   also check above again at the question. I screen shoted what I see when I inspect the color I want to find

Comment: check above in the question that is what I see, also you must be on the europe supreme website, which has different urls

Comment: you could try using a free vpn from the chrome store to view the same website as I am if you want